# Reduce white spacing before a SINGLE chapter heading in memoir class

Tags: chapters, memoir, preamble, white-space

I am using `memoir` document class. I wanted to decrease the space preceding my chapter headings, and I want to do it individually because I do not want to decrease white space before other headings (ToC, glossary, etc.).

It perfectly works writing in my `main.tex` this:

```
\frontmatter
    % ToC...

\makeatletter
\let\savedchap\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead{\vspace*{-3cm}\savedchap}
\mainmatter
    \input{chapter1.tex}
    \input{chapter2.tex}
    \input{chapter3.tex}
\let\@makechapterhead\savedchap
\makeatother

\backmatter
    % glossary...
```

But I want to avoid this solution because it is strongly recommended that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` shoud be in the preamble. What could be a reliable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `memoir`, `\@makechapterhead` begins with `\chapterheadstart`, whose default meaning is

```
\vspace*{\beforechapskip}
```

so all you need is to change `\beforechapskip` to your liking when in `\mainmatter`.

The default value is 50pt and 3cm is about 85pt.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-35pt}}
\AddToHook{cmd/backmatter/after}{\setlength{\beforechapskip}{50pt}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\backmatter

\chapter{Another test}

\end{document}
```

I used `oneside` just to avoid blank pages in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Great. Concise. Working.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `\vspace{-1.0cm}`. Obviously, you can change the 1.0 to any number based on how much space you want to reduce.

Comment: This was the naive solution I adopted at the beginning, but it didn't work.